# how to set button right outside textarea but when the textarea height increase than the button must goes down with textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I set TextArea and Button with two different div. div1 has textarea and div2 has button. Now I want do when the textarea height increase button must goes down with text area.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I think you need a clear "float:left" or make "float:left" button div

Comment: Can you add some piece of code. so that we can make changes to the code and make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```js
$.each($('textarea'), function() {
  var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;

  var resizeTextarea = function(el) {
    $(el).css('height', 'auto').css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
  };
  $(this).on('keyup input', function() {
    resizeTextarea(this);
  }).removeAttr('data-autoresize');
});

$("textarea").on("keyup", function() {
  var textareaHeight = $(this).height();
  var buttonHeight = $(".div2 button").height()
  var move = parseInt(textareaHeight - buttonHeight)
  $(".div2 button").css("margin-top", move);
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Can do it using css, then why javascript.

```css
textarea { resize: vertical; }
textarea{
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
 <textarea class="box" style="height: 50px;"></textarea><br>
 <button class="btn" type="submit" value="submit">Submit &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </button>
 </form>
```